# How can I increment counter when the value in another column changes without sorting the column?

Tags: sql

I have the following table
[image: I have the following table]

And I need to be able to increment the counter value when the Name changes in SQL

[image: And I need to be able to increment the counter value when the Name changes in SQL]

Comment: What fixes shown rows ordering in source, what ORDER BY expression? Without it your visual rows order is fake.

Comment: mysql and postgresql are two different database products with different implementations of sql. Removed the conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you actually use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a column that specifies the ordering of the columns -- because SQL tables represent unordered sets.  If you have one, you can do use a gap-and-islands trick with the difference of row numbers:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by name, seqnum - seqnum_2 order by <ordercol>) as value
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by <ordercol>) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by <ordercol>) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
order by <order col>;
```